# webapi how to route help page to home page

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET-Web-API project with a generated help area. I would like to route the home page to be pointing to the help page. How can this be done?
I've tried to modify the area registration like below but it is not working

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
            "HomePage",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

        context.MapRoute(
            "HelpPage_Default",
            "Help/{action}/{apiId}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

        HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591810/1579626](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19591810/1579626)