# Setting Help Page as default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a C# .Net 4.5 Web Api application to which I have added a Help Page such as the one shown [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages).

When a developer launches the Web Api application in Visual Studio, I would like the help page to come up.

I would like to accomplish this by the using routing (such as a change to WebApiConfig.cs or Global.asax.cs) as opposed to a setting in the project's properties.

In the WebApiConfig.cs file I tried adding the following -

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/help");
```

That did not work. Does anyone know how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? What is shown instead?

Answer (score 7):

Two years late, but for the benefit of Googlers like myself - A way to do it  (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334218/5192880)) is simply to modify the `RegisterArea` method in the `HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs` class in the HelpPage Area to contain a blank route. Example -

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "HelpPage_Default",
            "Help/{action}/{apiId}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });
        context.MapRoute(
            "Help Area",
            "",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index" });

        HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```